# how to upload laravel project to subdomain with database

Tags: laravel

I try to upload laravel project on subdomain, upload whole folder on subdomain and move public folder to main directory and change in index file but show directory of laravel folder.

Comment: why did you move public folder? if you change public folder location, you have to change path in index.php file in public folder